# Удаление параметра из строки GET по регулярному выражению

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url

Помогите с правильным составлением регулярного выражения  для `preg_replace` , точнее мне нужно удалить из строки какой либо параметр `GET`

К примеру, строка `cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&p=2&q=44` из которой мне надо удалить параметр `p` вне зависимости в какой позиции он стоит, возможно это `?p=2` или же `&p=2`. Для этого использую такое регулярное выражение: `{\?|\&(p=)[0-9]}`

```
$s = preg_replace('/{\?|\&(p=)[0-9]}/', '','cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&p=2&q=44');
```

Но нормальных результатов оно не дает, что я не правильно составил тут? (делал по учебнику)

Comment: по какому учебнику, если не секрет? )

Comment: @Jean-Claude А в `cbook.php?p=2` знак вопроса надо удалить. У меня получилось что-то вроде [`(?:&|(?(?=\?[^&]*&)(\?)|\?))p=\d+(?(1)&?)`](https://regex101.com/r/dTAykM/1) (заменить на `'$1'`).

Comment: А ещё и [так можно](https://ideone.com/iZjz2z).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бутор - эти регулярки, проще всего так

```
$http = parse_url('/cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&p=2&q=44');
parse_str($http['query'], $output);
if(isset($output['p'])) {
  unset($output['p']);
}
$new = $http["path"] . '?' . http_build_query($output);
echo $new;
```

Пример https://repl.it/repls/KlutzyLargePike

Comment: В вопросе неполный url)

Comment: @vp_arth ну ок, уговорил.

Answer (score 4):

Без регулярных выражений:

```
list($path, $query) = explode('?', 'cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&p=2&q=44');
parse_str($query, $q);
// $q - массив параметров

unset($q['p']);
$query = http_build_query($q);

$url = "{$path}?$query";

echo $url; // cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&q=44
```

Comment: хах, в этот раз я не успел написать :D

Comment: прям почти слово в слово,  мысль была еще учесть `#` только (:

Comment: Ну так, функции стандартные)

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо! но у меня почему то конструкция в первой строке с квадратными скобками вызывает ошибку( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Z:\home\rrr\www\r.php on line 2

Comment: Это для php7, сейчас уберу

Comment: `list($path, $query)` напишите

Answer (score 3):

Для корректного удаления подстроки понадобится шаблон, состоящий из трёх альтернатив:

> Если удаляемый элемент находится сразу после вопросительного знака, но ***не является*** единственным GET-параметром
>
> > *(в этом случае надо оставить знак "?", и удалить знак "&" вместе с удаляемым элементом)*
>
> Если удаляемый элемент находится сразу после вопросительного знака, и ***является*** единственным GET-параметром
>
> > *(в этом случае надо удалить знак "?", и все остальные символы после него)*
>
> Если удаляемый элемент находится в любой другой позиции подстроки
>
> > *(в этом случае, вместе с удаляемыми символами надо удалять и знак "&", предшествующий удаляемой подстроке)*

Шаблон будет иметь следующий вид:

> `'~(?<=\?)p=\d+&|&p=\d+|\?p=\d+$~'`

В комплекте с PHP-функцией он будет выглядеть таким образом:

> `echo preg_replace('~(?<=\?)p=\d+&|&p=\d+|\?p=\d+$~', '', $str);`

Тестировался на следующих строках:

> `cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&crop=4&p=2&q=44`
>
> `cbook.php?idc=n&ids=n&p=2&q=44`
>
> `cbook.php?p=2&idc=n&ids=n`
>
> `cbook.php?idc=n&p=2`
>
> `cbook.php?p=2`

**[Посмотреть результаты](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f25f63b896a49027f8f3ce684551c6617e3cba8)**

Comment: `?idc=n&ids=n&crop=4&p=2&q=44`

Comment: @vp_arth результатом будет: `?idc=n&ids=n&cro&q=44` Или что вы хотели сказать?

Comment: А, увидел ) Сейчас исправлю, спс )

Comment: [В `cbook.php?p=2&idc=n&ids=n&q=44`  вместо `?` появляется `&`](https://regex101.com/r/qHlxn3/1)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew да, я как раз только что всё исправил и отредактировал свой ответ. Благодарю )